# Presenting Facebook Share Dialog causes Facebook crash

Tags: android, facebook

When displaying a Facebook share dialog using the following code, the Facebook crashes.

```
FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder builder = 
    new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(activity);

FacebookDialog shareDialog = builder.build();
return shareDialog.present();
```

This is the stack trace that is returned:

```
04-29 15:47:52.929  32647-32647/? E/ACRA﹕ ACRA caught a StackOverflowError exception for com.facebook.katana. Building report.
04-29 15:47:52.934    2214-2214/? E/display﹕ invalid gralloc handle (at 0x0)
04-29 15:47:52.944  32647-32647/? E/fb4a(:<default>):ACRA﹕ Handling exception for crash
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at android.os.Parcel.writeInt(Parcel.java:484)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:608)
            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1201)
...
04-29 15:47:54.609  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ java.lang.StackOverflowError
04-29 15:47:54.609  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.os.Parcel.writeInt(Parcel.java:484)
04-29 15:47:54.609  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:608)
04-29 15:47:54.609  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
04-29 15:47:54.609  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
04-29 15:47:54.609  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1201)
...
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7414)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.finishActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2480)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:4303)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at com.facebook.base.activity.FbFragmentActivity.finish(FbFragmentActivity.java:313)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity.a(PlatformWrapperActivity.java:489)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity.e(PlatformWrapperActivity.java:401)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity.c(PlatformWrapperActivity.java:374)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity.a(PlatformWrapperActivity.java:269)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at com.facebook.base.activity.FbFragmentActivity.onCreate(FbFragmentActivity.java:171)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5428)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:164)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5350)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 15:47:54.624  32647-32647/? E/CatchMeIfYouCan﹕ Process (<default>) is exiting...
```

It appears that `FbFragmentActivity.finish` is causing a stack overflow trying to create a parcel, but I can't determine what is causing that process to enter an infinite loop. So far this has only been replicable on Samsung devices.

Edit:
Removed debug code from code snippet.

Comment: Are you using official Facebook SDK?
The `builder.setFragment(null);` line looks suspisious and unnecessary. Try to run without it.

Comment: Thanks @VadymVL the `builder.setFragment(null);` isn't necessary to replicate the problem. It was added while I was experimenting trying to narrow down what was causing the problem.

Yes, I am using the latest (3.21.1) official SDK.

Comment: The latest Facebook [Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x) is 4.0.1. Maybe this is the problem, cause v.3 is deprecated now.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention, I will look into this.

Comment: Do you have the key hashes set up in your app settings?

Comment: @VadymVL the line `builder.setFragment(null);` was added in debugging as I tried to characterize the problem. It happens with and without that line.

Comment: @VadymVL at the time I was running the latest version of the Facebook SDK, but indeed upgrading to the 4.0.1 version fixed the problem.